Grouping a column up to 30 !! in Excel 2016
as seen, there are 3 a, 4 b, 7 c, 11 d, 6 f, and other id groups. here I want to divide the IDs into groups. it can be divided up to 30, but ids that are a group within themselves should not be divided. So as seen here, the first group can consist of 25 ids. If we were to divide by 30, then one of the F ids would overflow into the next group, but I don't want that to happen. In the same way, the next group is 29.
because the k id after pp is 6 and since the previous group cannot be 35 and a group cannot be more than 30, the k id is included in the next group.
The next group is 20. Because we cannot include v, that is, we cannot divide it. The next group is 19. Since we cannot divide v and we cannot divide the next x, this group consists only of v. In short, we can divide up to 30 but we cannot separate the groups from themselves.
Likewise, grouping ids should be taken from grouping numbers. Ex. Grup 20, Grup 29 .. How can I do this func, vba ? somehow I could not succeed. Can you help ? thank you in advance. (In both pictures, the grouping on the left is wrong and the grouping on the right is right
enter image description here.)enter image description here
NOTE :
I thank you very much for your valuable response. However, unfortunately, it does not work this way in my scenario. So in my table, the IDs are in column G and it looks quite complicated. It is not ordered and it contains mixed expressions of numbers and letters. So IDs consist of mixed expressions such as NX6OQ7 or 87ASP3.
Let me repeat my thought; let's say G2-G8 is NX6OQ7, G9-G30 is 87ASP3, G31-G34 is HOP5FX, G35 is KLOKX4, G36-G55 is 3YTH6C, G56-G64 is XYTSX9 and G65-G78 is OPLOX5.
Now three things are important when grouping. 1: each group should not exceed 30. 2: IDs should not be split. 3: groups should be named with the group index. So here the first group should have NX6OQ7 and 87ASP3 and the group name should be Group 29.
(groups cannot exceed 30. HOP5FX is not included in this group because it is 4 and indivisible).
The second group should be HOP5FX, KLOKX4, 3YTH6C and the group name should be Group 25. And it should follow this logic.
frankly, I tried chatgpt and I was able to get the result on the left. more precisely, it was the healthiest result. i should also mention that my excel knowledge is not good. but I am trying. thanks.

You're not making a lot of sense to me, can you edit the question so it becomes clearer? (format the whole thing into blocks instead of one long text), include your data in text format (using TableMarkdown perhaps), include raw data (what you start with), a desired result, and the formula(s)/code you used.

Also, if there would be 6*a, 23*b, 22*c, 8* d, 1*e; would you expect it to result in group 1: a,b,e & group 2: c,d; or group 1: a,b & group 2: c,d & group 3 e?

Why is everyone angry here? I just asked a question :) My friend, order and grouping are important here. ( group 1: a,b group 2: c,d and group 3: e is correct. and their names should be 'Group 29' for a,b, 'Group 30' for c,d and 'Group 1' for e. ) So if there are 7 a, 22 b, 4 c, 1 d, 25 f, the first group should be a,b. Not a,b,d. So a,b will be 'Group 29'. c,d,f will be 'Group 30'.  IDs are in column G and can contain letters and numbers. It's very difficult for me, I can't do it. I hope you can find the time. Thank you for your time.

this problem is solved. thank you.

="Grup "&DROP(
 INDEX(
       REDUCE({0,1},G2:G60,
       LAMBDA(x,y,
              LET(v,TAKE(x,-1,1),
                  n,TAKE(x,-1,-1),
                  w,COUNTIF(G2:G60,y),
              VSTACK(x,
                     IF(COUNTIF(G2:y,y)=1,
                        IF(v+w>30,
                           HSTACK(w,n+1),
                           HSTACK(v+w,n)),
                        TAKE(x,-1))))))
       ,,2),1)

This creates a rolling counter of the COUNTIF of the id's in the range resetting prior to exceeding 30 and adding a number to the group.
INDEX indexes the group only, ignoring the rolling counter.
Or using older Excel:
=IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2)=1,IF(COUNTIF(H$1:H1,H1)+COUNTIF(G$2:G$60,G2)>30,H1+1,H1),H1))

man thank you very much for your time. but in the 2016 version I guess I can't use lambda. that's why it gives an error.

In G2 you could use: =IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2)=1,IF(COUNTIF(H$1:H1,H1)+COUNTIF(G$2:G$60,G2)>30,H1+1,H1),H1))

this problem is solved. thank you.
